# Commitar com uma versão antiga em uma versão nova

Tags: git

Fiz algumas alterações em alguns arquivos, porém antes que eu desse o commit um outro desenvolvedor havia subido outras alterações (algumas na mesma pasta que fiz alterações), existe algum meio de alterar o arquivo só com minhas alterações (que são com o arquivo anterior ao commit do outro desenvolvedor) sem alterar o que foi feito por ele?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Olá,bom pelo o que você disse parece que existe conflito,o git avisa quando eles acontecem,compara os 2 códigos e mostra a linha onde há diferença (quando há mudança na mesma linha).

Tem um guia muito legal que eu li sobre resolver conflitos:

https://metring.com.br/guia-resolvendo-conflitos-no-git

Mas explicando rapidamente é o seguinte:

[image: Basicamente quando o git mostrar os conflito]

Basicamente, quando o git mostrar os conflitos,você só precisa apagar a parte que seu colega fez e manter só sua parte. Assim:

[image: Você só precisa apagar a parte que seu colega fez e manter só sua parte]

*OBS:O que esta entre o HEAD e ====== é a sua parte e o que está entre o ===== e master é a do seu colega.

Espero ter ajudado,mas leia o artigo que é muito mais detalhado.

Isso q eu te falei é na hora do push,parando pra ler sua pergunta novamente, se isso foi no commit,por acaso não foi porque você tentou commitar na mesma branch do outro desenvolvedor??

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).